# Implementing protocol on closure in Swift

Tags: types, enums, swift, prototype

I would like to create some functions in my Swift project that can accept either an object, or a closure which returns that object type. I could of course define the same function with multiple signatures in each place, but that's verbose. I also would like to be able to create type-safe lists of these object/object-returning-closures but can't do that without some common type describing both things.

## This is what I would like to do

```
typealias StringClosure = () -> String

protocol Stringable {
    func toStringClosure() -> StringClosure
}

extension String : Stringable {
    func toStringClosure() -> StringClosure {
        return { return self }
    }
}

extension StringClosure : Stringable {
    func toStringClosure() -> StringClosure {
        return self
    }
}

func printStringable(a : Stringable) {
    print(a.toStringClosure()())
}


var stringableList : Stringable[] = ["cat", {return "dog"}, "gecko"]

for stringable in StringableList {
    printStringable(stringable)
}
```

But this does not work, because I can't actually extend my `StringClosure` type to implement `Stringable`. I could make `stringableList` a list of `Any` types, but that's not type safe.

## The enum solution

One solution is that I could make an enum type, but that means I have to explicitly annotate everywhere I use these types with the enum, which is lame. That would look like this:

```
enum StringableEnum {
    case Str(String)
    case Fun(StringClosure)
}

func printStringableEnum(a : StringableEnum) {
    switch (a) {
    case let .Str(value):
        print(value)
    case let .Fun(value):
        print(value())
    }
}

var enumList : StringableEnum[] = [.Str("cat"), .Fun({return "dog"}), .Str("gecko")]

for element in enumList {
    printStringableEnum(element)
}
```

It's not bad, but it requires the user of my API to now know about this enum, and label their parameters with `.Str` or `.Fun` every time they call my `printStringableEnum` function. Not exactly a nice API!

This may be too much to ask of the language, but does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: You mean `extension String : Stringable ...`

Comment: What is the actual goal here? You want to provide a way for the user of your API to pass a lazily calculated string with the idea that the value of the string may change between the time that the function is called and when the value is used?

Comment: @drewag yes exactly. Or so you can have side effects triggered by the closure. In my application it's a state machine, and when defining a state transition you either can just specify the next state OR a closure that returns the next state and potentially emits values, creates side effects, whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in this case, the simplest solution might be the best. Don't allow Strings to be passed directly in, instead require closures. It isn't very hard to turn a string into a  closure:

```
let myString = "Hello"
printStringable({return  myString})
```

You could even create a function to turn a value into a closure for convenience:

```
func f<T>(value : T) -> () -> T  {
    return {return value}
}

printStringable(f("Hello"))
printStringable(f(myString))
```

Although I don't think the few characters saved is worth it the potentially confusing function name.

**Edit**:

You could also improve your enum like so:

```
enum StringableEnum {
    case Str(String)
    case Fun(() -> String)

    init(_ string : String) {
        self = .Str(string)
    }

    init(_ closure : () -> String) {
        self = .Fun(closure)
    }

    var value : String {
        switch(self) {
            case let .Str(value):
                return value
            case let .Fun(closure):
                return closure()
        }
    }
}
```

This means that you can create a enum from any of the supported types like so:

```
var stringable = StringableEnum("Hello")
stringable = StringableEnum({return "Hello"})
```

and you can get the string out by doing

```
stringable.value
```

Comment: One issue with this is that I actually simplified my issue somewhat before posting. My closures sometimes take parameters, so I have several different "closure" types, all of which I would like to be able to accept. I'd like to be able to take e.g. `(Int, String) -> String`, `(Int) -> String`, `() -> String`, AND raw `String`. I don't want my user to need to curry all these themselves. Currently it's not a big issue, I'm just using overloads, but it means that each function I define I need to define n times, once for each signature.

Comment: @wxs, ya ultimately I don't think there is a way around the extra work for you if your really don't want to put any extra work onto the user of the API ;)

Comment: I don't really mind the extra work for me in the worst case. But it also means that my users will never be able to create a list of `Stringables`, so stops me from providing API functions which take in those lists, as overloads don't help me in that case.

Comment: @wxs, ok, ya, in that case you will have to use composition like you are doing with your enum solution. You could possibly improve the interface of the enum by providing an initializer for each type so the user doesn't have to manually specify the specific case.

Comment: @wxs You could also provide a method to easily get the value out of the enum.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I've updated the question with my understanding of this proposal. Definitely a promising route.

Comment: @wxs, you misunderstood me slightly. I updated my answer with what I meant.

Comment: You should be able to omit the return in the closure, so just `{"Hello"}`.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Don't do the following. It works as of Beta 4, but relies on a feature that Apple doesn't want the public using and intends to remove before the 1.0 release of Swift.

---

`@auto_closure` might work for you, but the issue with that is that it seems you can't pass explicit closures to `@auto_closure` parameters.

Another alternative is to treat everything as closures, and use Swift's `__conversion` feature to implicitly convert strings to StringClosures where needed:

```
typealias StringClosure = () -> String

extension String {
    func __conversion() -> StringClosure {
        return { self } // 'return' can be omitted inside a single-expression closure
    }
}

// type inferencing automatically figures out that
// stringableList should be [StringClosure] and applies
// the conversion method to promote the string entries into
// self-returning closures
var stringableList = ["cat", { println("side-effects are bad"); return "dog"}, "gecko"]

func printStringClosure(s: StringClosure) {
    println(s())
}

for s in stringableList {
    printStringClosure(s)
}

printStringClosure("test")
printStringClosure { let a = 5*5; return "\(a)" }
```

Comment: This is it! I didn't know about `__conversion`, thanks

Comment: Ah, I spoke too soon. Chris Lattner (lead designer of Swift) just stated on the dev forums that __conversion is *not* meant for public use, and they intend to remove it before the final release.

Comment: That would explain why I never saw it. Well that's a shame… I guess I should un-accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that swift has the option to create lazily calculated variables like so (they are not restricted to classes / structs):

```
var lazy : String {
    return "Hello"
}

printStringable(lazy)
```

This is a simpler solution to your lazy calculations / closures that have side effects problem if you don't need parameterized closures.

Comment: Interesting, I'd forgotten about those. In my real case, though, callbacks don't return the same value every time, so can't be simply lazy-evaluated parameters.